# Reactjs: Destructuring and formatting of params?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Working through a reactjs tutorial and found this (IMO) neat little feature that's demonstrating the destructuring of react parameters into a JSX object like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class MyButton extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <a {...this.props} >Discover Things!</a>
        );
    };
}
```

and example of use:

```
<MyButton className='btn btn-primary' href="//02geek.com" target="_blank" />
```

and the result:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="//02geek.com" target="_blank" >Discover Things!</a>
```

The more I'm looking at this and google for it, the more perplexed I'm getting. Who/what is responsible for taking the properties passed from the client, and then from the MyButton component's ... notation, formatting it out like this?

I'm assuming this is react/jsx hocus pocus? I'm not including any 3rd party transformers that I'm aware of that might be doing this. Pretty basic stuff for now.

Comment: You just putting all the props for MyButton using spread operator (...) to your <a> element and get a desired result. What is the question here?
Can you specify your question?

Comment: Was my answer relevant to you question? Was it understandable? I'm not sure how deep you want to go into the explanations.

Comment: 1) spread operations don't normally work against objects, only iterables. 2) Even if it could, the param object looks something like this: { className: 'btn btn-sm', href: '//02geek, target: '_blank' } and what is the magic that takes that object and formats it out as className='btn btn-sm' href='//02geek.com' target='_blank'

Answer (score 2):

When you use your custom component `MyButton` it looks kind of like a HTML-tag that you're setting some attributes on (like `className` and `href`). But you are really setting the component (`MyButton`) properties (or `props`). So if you do a `console.log(this.props.className)` inside of `MyButton` it will (in this example) print "btn btn-primary".

So all props that you set when you use `<MyButton className='btn btn-primary' href="//02geek.com" target="_blank" />` will be available inside `MyButton`, through `this.props`.

What happens inside `MyButton` is that it takes the `this.props` object (the one with values like `{ className: 'btn btn-primary'}`) and [spreads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) them into an ordinary `<a>`-tag. This means that the a-tag will get these values passed down as attributes. So in this example it's the exact equivalent of this:

```
<a clasName={this.props.className} href={this.props.href} target={this.props.target} >Discover Things!</a>
```

JSX [(read slightly more here)](http://buildwithreact.com/tutorial/jsx), which lets us deal with HTML inside of Javascript this way, will translate the above to

```
React.createElement(
  'a', 
  { 
     className: "btn btn-primary",
     href: "//02geek.com",
     target: "_blank"
  },
  "Discover Things!"
);
```

As a last step, React will also make the final translation from "className" to just="class" ("class" can't be used inside of Javascript because it's a a [reserved word](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)).

So when all these steps are done, React takes care of turning `React.createElement` calls to into actual DOM elements that you can see in your browser. In this case the output is:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="//02geek.com" target="_blank" >Discover Things!</a>
```

Comment: but the basic spread operator does not work against objects, it's intention is to work against iterables such as arrays.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't link to the specific part, but the link I posed about the spread operator has a section on "Spread in object literals"  which is what you'd want to read up on. It's a pretty new feature, but since many (if not most) React projects use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile ES6 (or even later features) to ES5, it's very common to see it in both code examples and in "real" production code.

Comment: yes, I am using babel, and I suspect such a helper might at play here. I'm just wondering where I would find reference to this feature that formats the html elements out for me in this manner. I simply can't find anything on it.

Comment: I edited my answer to include yet another step that JSX takes takes care of.    The last step is that React takes care of turning `React.createElement` calls to into actual DOM elements that you can see in your browser.

Comment: Hehe, yeah I guess you have to stop asking questions at [some point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down).. ;) Feel free to  give someone else the "accepted" answer if a better one comes along.

Answer (score -2):

So here's the answer I was looking for...
    https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/07bbe37bc42b6d4aef81

JSX has extended the functionality of the spread (...) operator to include objects and has a proposal that this functionality is added to the ES7 specification.

Comment: Even when you got thoughtful answer covering all aspects from spread operators to JSX attribute translations, you still self answering :-\